# Join 2 tables using Oracle with SUM query?

Tags: oracle, join

I have 2 queries

Q1:

```
SELECT tc_ghy07,tc_ghy12
FROM tc_ghy_file
WHERE tc_ghy02 = 'DNF-000414'
      AND tc_ghy01=TO_CHAR(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE))
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+
| TC_GHY07 | TC_GHY12 |
+----------+----------+
|       16 |        0 |
+----------+----------+
```

Q2:

```
SELECT ( SUM(DECODE(tc_soa38,NULL,0,tc_soa38)+ decode(tc_soa39,NULL,0,tc_soa39*1.5) 
+ DECODE(tc_soa40,NULL,0,tc_soa40 * 1.6) + decode(tc_soa41,NULL, 0,tc_soa41 * 2) +  
    decode(tc_soa42,NULL,0,tc_soa42
* 2.1) + DECODE(tc_soa43, NULL, 0,tc_soa43 * 2.7) 
+ DECODE(tc_soa44,NULL, 0,tc_soa44 * 3) + DECODE(tc_soa45, NULL,0,tc_soa45 *
3.9)) ) / 8 AS result
FROM tc_soa_file
WHERE tc_soa33 = 'BU'
      AND tc_soa04 = 'DNF-000414'
      AND year(tc_soa07) = year(current_date);
```

Result:

```
+--------+
| RESULT |
+--------+
|     20 |
+--------+
```

How can I join 2 these tables into one query?

I have tried Union All or Cross join but it's not right.
Thanks for helping

I want to query 2 these query in one query and the result will like this

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
|  TC_GHY07 | TC_GHY12 | RESULT |
+-----------+----------+--------+
|        16 |        0 |     20 |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Edit: Join condition is `tc_ghy02=tc_soa04`

Comment: We'll never know if you don't tell us what the join condition is. Also, reduce our effort by providing some sample data and expected result.

Comment: `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)` is invalid for Oracle - are you sure you are using that?

Comment: I have tried `select year(CURRENT_DATE) from dual` and result is 2019, it's ok, but how about `select year(SYSDATE) from dual`

Comment: As @KaushikNayak said, you have to have join condition to join your two result tables. And one more comment, for the sake of clean code, you should change `DECODE(tc_soa39,NULL,0,tc_soa39*1.5)` to `NVL(1.5 * tc_soa39, 0)` or `COALESCE(1.5 * tc_soa39, 0)` and so on.

Comment: If `select year(CURRENT_DATE) from dual` works for you, then you are **not** using Oracle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90cf30cc808f67c2dbabd76825ff901b

Comment: How about this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions036.htm#SQLRF00628)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use this query

```
SELECT a.tc_ghy07,
       a.tc_ghy12,
       r.result
  FROM tc_ghy_file a
 INNER JOIN (select b.tc_soa04,
                    (SUM(DECODE(b.tc_soa38, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa38) +
                         decode(b.tc_soa39, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa39 * 1.5) +
                         DECODE(b.tc_soa40, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa40 * 1.6) +
                         decode(b.tc_soa41, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa41 * 2) +
                         decode(b.tc_soa42, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa42 * 2.1) +
                         DECODE(b.tc_soa43, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa43 * 2.7) +
                         DECODE(b.tc_soa44, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa44 * 3) +
                         DECODE(b.tc_soa45, NULL, 0, b.tc_soa45 * 3.9))) / 8 AS result 
             from tc_soa_file b
             where b.tc_soa33 = 'BU'
                   and year(b.tc_soa07) = year(current_date)
             Group by tc_soa04
             ) r on r.tc_soa04 = a.tc_ghy02
 WHERE a.tc_ghy02 = 'DNF-000414'
   AND a.tc_ghy01 = TO_CHAR(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but because of sum, so it's error  `not a single-group group function` but when I added `GROUP BY a.tc_ghy07, a.tc_ghy12`, it's a emty query, no result